# Angular 2 trigger text crossfade animation on data change

Tags: angular, animation

I have an Angular 2 component which displays a heading. There is a service which listens for data changes from other components and can change the string value of the heading.

I want to use Angular animations to fade in the text when it loads and then to dissolve/crossfade when the heading text changes. I have the fadein working but am unsure how to trigger the crossfade and whether the same transition would be used.

Here is the code so far:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, style, transition, animate, trigger } from '@angular/core';
import { DataTransferService } from '../services/data-transfer.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-page-header',
    template: '<h1 [innerHTML]="heading" [@fadeMe]="heading" *ngIf="heading != null"></h1>',
    animations: [
        trigger('fadeMe', [
            transition('void => *', [style({opacity: 0}), animate('500ms ease-in', style({opacity: 1}))])
        ])
    ]
})
export class PageHeaderComponent implements OnInit {

    public heading: string = '';

    constructor(
        private pageHeaderService: DataTransferService
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.pageHeaderService.pageHeaderData$.subscribe(
            data => {
                this.heading = data['heading'];
            });
    }

}
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Although this is 6 months old, I just bumped into this yesterday.
Here's a quick solution for this:

If you think about it, you will realize that in order to crossfade **you must have both previous and current titles at hand**. So what's left now is to hide and show both interchangeably.

```
    <!-- class title sets both to the same absolute location -->
    <h1 class="title" [@crossfade]="state1">{{title1}}</h1>
    <h1 class="title" [@crossfade]="state2">{{title2}}</h1>

animations: [
        trigger('crossfade', [
            state('show', style({ opacity: 1 })),
            state('hide', style({ opacity: 0 })),
            transition('* => show', animate('1s ease-in')),
            transition('show => hide', animate('1s ease-out'))
        ])]

...

    title1: string;
    title2: string;
    state1 = 'hide';
    state2 = 'hide';

 switchTitles() {
        const newTitle = ... //get new title
        if (this.state1 === 'show') {
            this.title2 = newTitle;
            this.state1 = 'hide';
            this.state2 = 'show';
        } else {
            this.title1 = newTitle;
            this.state2 = 'hide';
            this.state1 = 'show';
        }
    }
```